# Division inaccurate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

If I perform the following operation in Javascript:

```
0.06120*400
```

The result is 24.48.

However, if I do this:

```
24.48/400
```

The result is:

```
0.061200000000000004
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zcDH7/

So it appears that Javascript rounds things differently when doing division and multiplication?

Using my calculator, the operation `24.48/400` results in the correct answer of `0.0612`.

How should I deal with Javascript's inaccurate division? I can't simply round the number off, because I will be dealing with numbers of varying precision.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is _always_ inaccurate. Javascript's not to blame.

Comment: Floating point operations are not meant to be _100%_ accurate. This applies to almost all programming languages, not just JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the correct result with simply using:

```
var a = 24.48/400;
console.log(a.toFixed(6));
```

And because `typeof a.toFixed(6) === 'string'` you can:

```
var a = 24.48/400;
console.log(parseFloat(a.toFixed(6)));
```

- The argument of `toFixed` is the number of decimals you want.